Python being sourced from multiple environments
So I am using this framework called frappe which seems to have messed Python environment initialization.
To provide some context, there is a command line tool named bench which is used to control the framework.
The command bench start works with a Procfile. Here are the contents of the Procfile:
redis_queue: redis-server config/redis_queue.conf

web: bench serve --port 8000

socketio: /home/amol/.nvm/versions/node/v22.3.0/bin/node apps/frappe/socketio.js


watch: bench watch


schedule: bench schedule
worker:  bench worker 1>> logs/worker.log 2>> logs/worker.error.log 


The command bench start runs this proc file internally.
I have used a virtual environment to set up the python virtual environment. Here are some of the commands I am able to run when the virtual environment is active:
(.venv) amol@amol-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench$ which python
/home/amol/WorkSpace/frappe/.venv/bin/python

(.venv) amol@amol-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench$ which bench
/home/amol/WorkSpace/frappe/.venv/bin/bench

(.venv) amol@amol-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench$ python
Python 3.12.3 (main, Sep 11 2024, 14:17:37) [GCC 13.2.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import frappe;
>>> frappe
<module 'frappe' from '/home/amol/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench/apps/frappe/frappe/__init__.py'>
>>> 

Now the command bench start that works with the Procfile seems to use a different Python environment than one being used by my terminal. This is the error that I get:
16:26:56 watch.1       | /home/amol/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench/env/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'frappe.utils.bench_helper' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frappe')


My understanding is that it is clearly using a different Python environment than the one used by my terminal.
This is the error encountered when I run bench watch using the command line.
(.venv) amol@amol-IdeaPad-Gaming-3-15ARH05:~/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench$ bench  watch
/home/amol/WorkSpace/frappe/frappe-bench/env/bin/python: Error while finding module specification for 'frappe.utils.bench_helper' (ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'frappe')

I was hoping if someone from the frappe team or someone otherwise well versed with Python virtual environments could help me with this issue.

What is Procfile?

@phd This is a file used by the command line tool 'bench' to control the framework. It is file generated by the framework specifying the commands that are run by the cli tool 'bench'. As can be seen from the content it used to run redis, web-server to serve html files, etc.

Frappe manages its own Python environment under ./env. Frappe and other apps (editable installs from ./apps), including their dependencies, will be installed under the env in your bench directory. The bench CLI manages this and uses the ./env/bin/python interpreter for all its needs.
While the bench CLI should be installed globally - I prefer pipx to avoid package conflicts. The bench CLI and Frappe typically use different environments, and by extension, interpreters.

Something may have gone wrong while creating your bench (instance) - the frappe-bench folder. You may run bench setup env to fix this.
If that's not sufficient, I would suggest manually setting up the environment again:
rm -rf ./env
python -m venv env  # be careful about using the right version of python here
./env/bin/python -m pip install -e ./apps/frappe
bench setup requirements --python

